# rails API error: Validation failed: Email is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I hope you are good. I try to implement google authentication to my rails API. I get error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email is invalid)
```

My user.rb:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :trackable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]

  def self.create_user_for_google(data)
    where(uid: data['email']).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = 'google_oauth2'
      user.uid = data['email']
      user.email = data['email']
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.password_confirmation = user.password
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

and my users_controller.rb looks:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def google_oauth2
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=#{params['id_token']}"
    response = HTTParty.get(url, format: :plain)
    
    user = User.create_user_for_google(response.parsed_response)
    
    render json: user
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the response for `HTTParty.get(url, format: :plain)`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there's no `email` in `response.parsed_response`

You're not supposed to make the request from your backend the way you do:

```
HTTParty.get "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=#{params['id_token']}"
```

You're supposed to redirect user's browser to `user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_url` (I think this URL helper comes from devise in routes.rb (look for `devise_for:`)

Then your user's browser shows the Google log in page (or, if user was already logged in, next step) then (still google) asks for their consent to share data, and only after receiving this consent google would redirect your user back to your app to an address that is called a callback (it looks like `omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"`)

And only in the controller/action that handles this callback, you'll see an email and a token you can save with your user and use it to signing in with google's oAuth protocol.

Don't worry, oAuth is confusing when you do it for the first time.

One of the clearest step-by-step example how to implement omni auth I could find is here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application